# build.gradle file always shows some error for my react native app that i build using expo cli

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, mobile-application, eas

I am having trouble in running build on my react-native mobile app (which is done using command "eas build -p andriod" in terminal at root level). When I remove .expo folder the build runs successfully but when this folder is added, it always shows error in the build.gradle file. If I try to run build, it fails. I want to add .expo folder because it contains manifest file where I want some permissions added and also to update the VERSION of my app so that playstore dosen't show the error that implies the version number of the app should be changed.

[My folder structure.
Note: I have intentionally added android folder in .expo to ignore it while uploading app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DchMf.png)